# Attribute selector on style doesn't work

Tags: jquery

i've to find the div within the "para" class which is visible at the moment.
I tried:

```
 $('.para div[style="display: block;"]').attr("id")
```

but it doesn't work.

I also wrote an example on js fiddle --> http://jsfiddle.net/JZFgp/3/

I'm thankful for any hints and solutions.

Mario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That will work fine, but your markup is invalid in the fiddle. Here's a [fixed version](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/JZFgp/1/):

```
<table> <!-- You didn't have a `table` or `tr` element -->
    <tr>
        <td class="para">
            <div id="TripSet" class="rounded-corner-region" style="display: none;">
            <div id="DriverSet" class="rounded-corner-region" style="display: none;">
            <div id="TimeSet" class="rounded-corner-region" style="display: block;">
            <div id="Loading" class="borderless-region" style="display: none;">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

Without the `table` and `tr` elements, the browser does its best to interpret your markup and ends up just removing the `td` (in Chrome at least), which means the `.para` part of your selector can no longer match.

---

**Edit**

It looks like Chrome (most likely others too but I haven't tested) is quite happy for you to omit the `tr` element, as long as there is a `table` element. It automatically adds a `tbody` and `tr` around your `td` elements.

Comment: My problem is this solution doesn't work within my page, although there are no missing tags. I always get a "undefined".

Comment: @Mario - You can see in the updated fiddle that it *should* work. Something else in your code must be causing the issue. Do you run it in a DOM ready event handler?

Comment: Yeah, i saw it and yes the the selector is in a $(document).ready(function(){ [code]} block.

Comment: @Mario - Try and make a fiddle with more of your actual code and markup. You may well discover the issue while doing that.

Comment: Or could it be possible that the reason i cannt "find" the right div is my use of $(selector).[show(id)/hide(id)]?

Comment: Yes, if `show` or `hide` affects the `style` attribute (I don't think it will - it should change the *property*, not the attribute), but I'm just guessing. I would need to see more code.

Comment: ok got it. The error was that the selector is executed by a function. This function on the other hand reacts on a change in a selectlist. During my testing i don't use the selectlist and so there was no change event..... head->desk.

Answer (score 1):

`$('.para div:visible').attr("id")` should work.

Comment: While that works (and in my opinion is a better solution) it doesn't really answer the question as why selecting on the style attribute did not work. But as I said, way better solution IMHO. :)

Comment: This solution only works if the divs are empty. In my page those divs aren't empty, or didn't understand the description here http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/ wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the style attribute reliably in a selector. Some browsers will leave the attribute value unchanged, while others will normalise the value.

In IE8 for example, reading the attribute value gives you `"display: block"` rather than `"display: block;"`, but you can't use a selector with `[style="display: block"]` (or `[style="display: block;"]`) to find the element.